# jQuery Load Function not working for non-existing file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to work on jQuery Load function. I am getting an unusual problem when loading a non-existing file.In my local pc it is showing 404 error for non-existing file. But on the live server the jQuery Load is loading the root file data when i attempt to load a non-existing file.

The jQuery load demo is [here.](http://www.demo.yogihosting.com/jquery/jquery-load/)

The problem can be seen on clicking the second try button.

Below is the jQuery code -

```
$("#loadNoTextFile").click(function (e) {
    $("#textNoData").load("no-file.txt", function (response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error")
            $("#textNoData").html("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
});
```

What can be the possible problem?

Comment: have you checked the file permission?

Comment: try using relative path. like `~/no-file.txt`

Comment: yeah i agree with muhammed.. you should try absolute paths.

Comment: @Bilal i don't think file permission has a role in it. The code is working perfectly in local pc.

Comment: then it might be the path

Comment: how can path, it is trying to load "no-file.txt" on the same folder where the jquery exists.

Comment: @yogihosting look at the network tab or using fiddler, your demo calls to http://www.demo.yogihosting.com/jquery/jquery-load/no-file.txt , which exists.
Check what it calls in your local pc.

Comment: As I understood, it seems that the server has the root page as default response when get's `404` errors. If you look at network tab, you'll see the status for non-existing file is `200` (success). because probably, the `404` error was handled and redirected to the root page (which means that your `load` method will show the root page, which is the response of for the `load`). Check the tab network in your local machine and see what response status code do you get from the request...the server should do the same.